# Question about WHERE EXISTS and subquery on MySQL Coursera page

Tags: mysql, sql

Edited again to add: the 2nd table ("dogs") have null user_guid values. If i filter out the NULL values then the `NOT IN` operator works without `WHERE`. And I still dont know why :|

---

Edited:
Sorry I realized that I flipped the question. The question was the number of users who are in "users" table and NOT in the "dogs" table.
My original code was:

```
select count(distinct u.user_guid)
from users u
where u.user_guid not IN (select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d)
```

Which got result of 0 count. The answer was supposed to be 2226
Only when I add the `WHEN` condition then i got the right answer:

```
select count(distinct u.user_guid)
from users u
where u.user_guid not IN (select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d
                         WHERE d.user_guid = u.user_guid);
```

I still don't know why the `WHERE` condition makes the difference here

---

The question was:

> How could you determine the number of unique users in the "users" table
> who were also in the "dogs" table?

The correct answer was supposed to be

```
select count(u.user_guid)
from users u
where u.user_guid IN (select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d
                         where u.user_guid=d.user_guid);
```

Now I don't understand the point of the last WHERE filter. I thought the "IN" operator would have already made sure to filter only for values of u.user_guid that also exists in the d.user_guid (ie. the "IN" operator would have ensured that there are matching values) , which is the same as what the WHERE condition did (ie. u.user_guid = d.user_guid). And yet when I run the 2 codes (with and without the last WHERE line), the results were different. I'm not sure where I went wrong :/

Comment: `where exists (select 1 from dogs as d where d.user_guid=u.user_guid)`

Comment: The in clause doesn't need `where u.user_guid=d.user_guid` , exists yes

Comment: what was the difference between the 2 result sets?

Comment: `The correct answer was supposed to be` I don't think this might be the correct answer. You need to group by user_guid and apply `having count(*)=1` to have unique values

Comment: @Kendle: sorry just edited. It's supposed to be `NOT IN`

Comment: @ErgestBasha: sorry I missed that out. Anyway I edited my questions (see the top). It's supposed to be `NOT IN` that was the confusion. I also added the result I got with and without the `WHERE` condition

Comment: @Tracey have you checked my answer ? It returns only the rows which are presented only once in the `users` table and are  found in the `dogs` table too

Comment: @Tracey with your updated question , you can replace exists with not exists in my answer and have the correct result

Comment: @ErgestBasha : thank you, but my question is more on why didn't my query `NOT IN` work without the `WHERE` condition? Because logically I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work and if I don't understand a simple `NOT IN` operator I can't be confident with my future queries :/

Answer (score 0):

Below query finds the users who exists and are not unique on the  `dogs` table , and based on the users found on the dogs table , only the unique values are returned  from the `users` table:

```
select u.user_guid
from users u
where exists ( select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d
                         where u.user_guid=d.user_guid
             )
group by user_guid
having count(*)=1;
```

The last where condition `where u.user_guid=d.user_guid` returns only the users from `dogs` table which are found on the `users` table, so it should produce wrong results in your case.

If you want only the number change `u.user_guid` with `count(u.user_guid)`

```
select count(u.user_guid)
from users u
where exists ( select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d
                         where u.user_guid=d.user_guid
             )
group by user_guid
having count(*)=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select unique users which are not available in dogs table then it's better to use `not exists`.

```
     select count(distinct u.user_guid) unique_users    
     from users u     
     where not exists (select 1 from dogs d where u.user_guid = d.user_guid);
```

`not exists` and `not in` are almost do the same job but they handled null in different ways. Below link will explain that

[NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

If you want to count unique users you might need `distinct` keyword if there are multiple rows for any user. For example: `count( distinct u.user_guid)`.

For `IN` you don't need `where u.user_guid=d.user_guid`. But I would suggest the solution using`exists`

Using`IN`:

```
select count( u.user_guid)
from users u
where u.user_guid IN (select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d);
```

Using `Exists`:

```
select count( u.user_guid)
from users u
where exists IN (select 1
                         from dogs d
                          where u.user_guid=d.user_guid);
```

Examples of `IN` and `exists`
In users table there are three value for user_guid. 1,2 and 3. 2 is there two times. But in dogs table user_guid are 2,3 and 5. 2 and 3 are common in both tables. Please check the queries and outputs.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table users(user_guid int);
 create table dogs(user_guid int);

 insert into users values(1);
 insert into users values(2);
 insert into users values(2);
 insert into users values(3);

 insert into dogs values(2);
 insert into dogs values(3);
 insert into dogs values(5);
```

Query: Using IN
select count(distinct u.user_guid) unique_users
from users u
where u.user_guid IN (select d.user_guid from dogs d );

Output:

| unique_users |
| --- |
| 2 |

Query: Using EXISTS

```
 select count(distinct u.user_guid) unique_users    
 from users u     
 where exists (select 1 from dogs d where u.user_guid = d.user_guid);
```

Output:

| unique_users |
| --- |
| 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b27ddb20134751403b937e030bc1b4bd)*

Comment: I did try<br/>
```select count( u.user_guid)
from users u
where u.user_guid IN (select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d);```<br/>
however this gives me result of 0. Also i have absolutely no idea how to format my comment and this is stressing me out :(

Comment: The below gives me the count of 2000+, whereas if I remove the `WHERE` condition, it gives me 0 result.  
    ````select count(distinct u.user_guid)
    from users u
    where u.user_guid NOT IN (select d.user_guid
                         from dogs d
                         where d.user_guid=u.user_guid);````

Comment: @Tracey since fist query is returning 0 rows it seems that you don't have any common user in both tables.

Comment: I have added an example. Please check.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer @Kazi , I updated my question above. Sorry but I realized the confusion was more with `NOT IN` , ie. finding count of users who are in the table 1 but NOT IN table 2. And I also added the result that i got with vs. without `WHEN` operator in my question now (0 count without `WHEN`, but 2226 with `WHEN`)

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur shouldn't be returned value 3 based on your data ?

Comment: Used distinct since OP asked for unique users.

Comment: if `IN` and `EXISTS` both seem to give the same result, why did you prefer `EXISTS` over `IN`? @KaziMohammadAliNur

Comment: @Tracey exists perform faster than in in most cases

Comment: Added in my question above but basically I found more details: the 2nd table ("dogs") have null user_guid values. If i filter out the NULL values then the `NOT IN` operator works without `WHERE`. But I still dont know why the NULL values affected the query that way :/

Comment: NULL value will effect the query using `not in`. That's why it's always better to use 'not exists'.

Comment: I have revised my answer for your new requirement

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I think you're overcomplicating things here.
If you do a simple join you only get the values which are in both tables.
If you do a left join the fields which aren't matched in the second table return null.
NB: if we join on a column which is nullable we could get false results but that's not good in any case.

> ```
> create table dogs (d int);
> create table user (u int);
> insert into dogs values
> (1),(2),(3),(4),
> (1),(2),(5),(6);
> insert into user values
> (1),(2),(3),(4),
> (1),(2),(7),(8);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d) as du 
> FROM dogs join user on d=u;
> ```
>
> ```
> | du |
> | -: |
> |  4 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d) as dd
> FROM dogs LEFT JOIN user on d=u
> WHERE u IS NULL;
> ```

> ```
> | dd |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=fe5d5e22da097fd266a70775b396a986)*

Answer (score 0):

ok so it's weird to answer my own question but I found out the reason why `IN` worked without the `WHERE` condition yet `NOT IN` absolutely needed the `WHERE` condition (in the case of my queries). It's because the "dogs" dataset has a few NULL `user_guid` values.

Eg. fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2tZodoumTUXzFZFJQ3n5r4/2)

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO users (id) VALUES (3);

CREATE TABLE dogs (
  id INT
);
INSERT INTO dogs (id) VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO dogs (id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO dogs (id) VALUES (NULL);
```

If I use `IN` without `WHERE`:

```
select count(distinct u.id)
from users u
where u.id in (select d.id
              from dogs d
                        );
```

the result is 1 (the value 3), because SQL just need to find the match for "3" once, no need to care about all other values including the `NULL` value.
But if I use `NOT IN` without the last `WHERE`, instead of giving me result of 2 (ID 1 and 2), the result was 0.

```
select count(distinct u.id)
from users u
where u.id not in (select d.id
                    from dogs d);
```

This is because SQL had to make sure the IDs 1 and 2 in users table didn't match with **any** of the rows in dogs table, meaning it had to compare **ALL** rows including the NULL rows. And NULL value is considered as unknown hence it can't be compared to a non-NULL value.
So I actually can just use `WHERE d.user_guid is not null` as well, it would also return the same number.